# Looping over an ansible dict for specific value

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

With ansible, looping over a list of items that return a dict(?) with listed values.

Basically I want to check a dict of packages to see if they are installed or not (and later on return a message for any missing packages).

Any loop/with_dict combo tried so far return various errors that the specific variable can't be found.

When querying the status itself (yum module) it does put the full output into the {{ pkg }} var, per package.

```
---
- name: Ansible tests playbook
  hosts: vms
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    pkgs:
      - yum-utils
      - mariadb-libs
  tasks:
    - name: Check packages
      yum:
        list: "{{ item }}"
        disablerepo: '*'
      register: pkg
      loop: "{{ pkgs }}"
```

If I then simply output the contents of {{ pkg.results }} with :

```
    - name: list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ pkg.results }}"
```

I get :

```
root@vm011:~/ovirt# ansible-playbook check.yml

PLAY [Ansible tests playbook] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm017.warp]

TASK [Check paclages] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm017.warp] => (item=yum-utils)
ok: [vm017.warp] => (item=mariadb-libs)

TASK [list] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm017.warp] => (item=None) =>
  msg:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    invocation:
      module_args:
        allow_downgrade: false
        conf_file: null
        disable_gpg_check: false
        disable_plugin: []
        disablerepo: '*'
        enable_plugin: []
        enablerepo: null
        exclude: null
        install_repoquery: true
        installroot: /
        list: yum-utils
        name: null
        security: false
        skip_broken: false
        state: installed
        update_cache: false
        update_only: false
        validate_certs: true
    item: yum-utils
    results:
    - arch: noarch
      envra: 0:yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch
      epoch: '0'
      name: yum-utils
      release: 50.el7
      repo: installed
      version: 1.1.31
      yumstate: installed
ok: [vm017.warp] => (item=None) =>
  msg:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    invocation:
      module_args:
        allow_downgrade: false
        conf_file: null
        disable_gpg_check: false
        disable_plugin: []
        disablerepo: '*'
        enable_plugin: []
        enablerepo: null
        exclude: null
        install_repoquery: true
        installroot: /
        list: mariadb-libs
        name: null
        security: false
        skip_broken: false
        state: installed
        update_cache: false
        update_only: false
        validate_certs: true
    item: mariadb-libs
    results:
    - arch: x86_64
      envra: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.el7_5.x86_64
      epoch: '1'
      name: mariadb-libs
      release: 1.el7_5
      repo: installed
      version: 5.5.60
      yumstate: installed
```

How can I get just the `yumstate`  value (installed, or otherwise), per package, into a separate variable ?

If, for instance, I try to debug the msg with

```
    - name: list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.yumstate }}"
      loop: "{{ pkg.results }}"
```

I get:

```
fatal: [vm017.warp]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'yumstate'
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looping correctly through the `pkg.results`, but in each item the `yumstate` is under another `results` key. you should use:

```
- name: list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.results.yumstate }}"
  loop: "{{ pkg.results }}"
```

i tried your code on my fedora, and the `results` for one of the 2 packages has as value a list, so the `item.results.yumstate` would not work: Fedora response for `yum utils`:

```
"item.results": [
    {
        "arch": "noarch",
        "epoch": "0",
        "name": "yum-utils",
        "nevra": "0:yum-utils-1.1.31-517.fc29.noarch",
        "release": "517.fc29",
        "repo": "fedora",
        "version": "1.1.31",
        "yumstate": "available"
    },
    {
        "arch": "noarch",
        "epoch": "0",
        "name": "yum-utils",
        "nevra": "0:yum-utils-1.1.31-518.fc29.noarch",
        "release": "518.fc29",
        "repo": "updates",
        "version": "1.1.31",
        "yumstate": "available"
    }
]
```

for `mariadb-libs`, no packages found, response was:

```
"item.results": []
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You did indeed point me in the correct way.

```
- name: list 
debug: 
  msg: "Package {{ item.results[0].name }} is {{ item.results[0].yumstate }}"
loop: "{{ pkg.results }}"
```

Did the trick, with just "{{ item.results.yumstate }}" it still returned an error

```
TASK [list] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [vm017.warp]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'yumstate'
```

Adding the `[0]` got me:

```
TASK [list] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm017.warp] => (item=None) =>
  msg: Package yum-utils is installed
ok: [vm017.warp] => (item=None) =>
  msg: Package mariadb-libs is installed
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider nested loops , also known aa "loops and includes" if you're attempting fancy things.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var